# Android task to enable button

Tags: android, audio, button, bitmap, imageview

Good morning, I have a button called next, and I want when the user clicks on it and he imported/captured an image it takes him to the next activity.
But when the user clicks on it and he didn't choose/capture an image it won't take him, it'll show a toast message that he needs to get an image first.

this is my next Button code

```
    final Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnNext.setEnabled(false);
```

and these are my camera and gallery codes

```
    btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

and this is the next button OnClick code

```
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {      
            MpClick.start();
            if (btnNext.isEnabled() == false)
            { 
                   Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this,
                            "Please get an image first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
            }
            else
            {
                Intent next = new Intent(StartActivity.this, Option.class);
                startActivity(next);
            }
        }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable the button on :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {}
```

If result = OK, enable and if result = false disable.
That would do it.

Comment: didnt understand u well, I have an onActivityResult ..
how do I use it with the button ?